# Spree API 3.7 : Images comes as separate object instead of embedded inside product itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api, spree

Spree API when hitting /products?include=images path gives the response in following format.

```
{
  "data": [...],
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "type": "image",
      "attributes": {
      "viewable_type": "Spree::Variant",
      "viewable_id": 3,
      "styles": [
        {
          "url": "/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--bd6df012d992b43227344ecb03dc0ab6e13b1555/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lMTkRoNE5EZytCam9HUlZRPSIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoidmFyaWF0aW9uIn19--504f95c059f17243e0d7d1312e2b387f26a40aff/bg.jpg",
          "width": "48",
          "height": "48"
        },
        {
          "url": "/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--bd6df012d992b43227344ecb03dc0ab6e13b1555/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lOTVRBd2VERXdNRDRHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--594f543b42e0bfafbe9d09df814e1d60837f9ef6/bg.jpg",
          "width": "100",
          "height": "100"
        },
        {
          "url": "/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--bd6df012d992b43227344ecb03dc0ab6e13b1555/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lOTWpRd2VESTBNRDRHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--46583de60196cb1eee5b4a704d67209eee40c09a/bg.jpg",
          "width": "240",
          "height": "240"
        },
        {
          "url": "/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--bd6df012d992b43227344ecb03dc0ab6e13b1555/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lOTmpBd2VEWXdNRDRHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--3b3e65d1d9c712d2d540e15aa84ca541eb12b365/bg.jpg",
          "width": "600",
          "height": "600"
        }
      ]
    }
  }],

  "meta": {
    "count": 14,
    "total_count": 14,
    "total_pages": 1
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "https://galific.herokuapp.com/api/v2/storefront/products?include=variants.images",
      "next": "https://galific.herokuapp.com/api/v2/storefront/products?include=variants.images&page=1",
      "prev": "https://galific.herokuapp.com/api/v2/storefront/products?include=variants.images&page=1",
      "last": "https://galific.herokuapp.com/api/v2/storefront/products?include=variants.images&page=1",
      "first": "https://galific.herokuapp.com/api/v2/storefront/products?include=variants.images&page=1"
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can see the image URL's are coming as included object. While developing for mobile its not a good idea to put the very crucial element (product image path in this case) in separate object. This require the mobile dev to loop unnecessary just to get the image path which can be provided within the image relationships object like this:

```
"images": {
  "data": [
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "image",
    "url" : 'image-path.jpg'
  }]
}
```

The image path should be included in data object itself rather than separated include object. Is there any way to do it without messing with source??

Comment: which Spree version are you on?

Comment: i am on spree 3.7